# Necessity of compactness of manifolds $M,N$ for smooth approximation of $W^{1,p}(M,N)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, sobolev-spaces, compact-manifolds

I'm currently studying the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(M,N)$ between manifolds $M,N$. One result by Schoen & Uhlenbeck is existence of approximation through $C^\infty(M,N)$-functions, if $M$ and $N$ are smooth and compact and $p \geq \dim M$.

A raw sketch of the result goes as follows. We use the embedding (by Whitney/Nash) of the target manifold $N$ into a Euclidean space. (Here we use smoothness.) Now we consider the smooth convolution approximation which is in $C^\infty(M, \mathbb{R}^k)$. A Poincaré inequality will show that the approximating sequence lies in some tubular neighbourhood of $N$ (here we use $p \geq \dim M$) and thus can be smoothly projected for the projected approximation to be in $C^\infty(M,N)$.

Where is compactness of the manifolds needed? Is it something in the proof? Or is something without compactness not welldefined at all?

I'd appreciate any help.

**Note:** Crossposted to [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250494/necessity-of-compactness-of-manifolds-m-n-for-smooth-approximation-of-w1-p).

Comment: One has that $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n; \mathbb R)$ is not embedded in the usual Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n; \mathbb R)$. One considers $C^\infty_c$, the class of compactly-supported smooth functions, which is dense in the closed subspace $W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb R^n; \mathbb R)$. All those subtleties disappear on compact manifolds. Maybe that's the only reason why one consider compact manifolds only? (Unfortunately I cannot answer this question myself, I don't know anything about those geometric analysis tools you mention)

Comment: I would be skeptical of the bit where you say "the convolution lies in a tubular neighborhood" if N is not compact. If M is not compact convolution itself is dangerous, and Giuseppe's comment is also relevant.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro So what you are saying is that in the euclidean case one either has only approximation on a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or if on $\mathbb{R}^n$ one can only approximate the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(M,N)$ with $C^\infty_c$ functions. Now if $M$ is not compact, the convolution approximation itself might not work, thus one only considers compact manifolds. Is that your idea?

Comment: @MikeMiller To be honest, i have a hard time imagining a tubular neighbourhood for some non-compact manifold, however the neighbourhood does exist even for non-compact manifolds. What exactly are you skeptic about?

Comment: That the convolution will always stay in the tubular neighbohood. For instance, one tubular neighborhood of the x-axis in $\Bbb R^2$ is the set of points whose y-coordinate satisfies $|y| < 1/(1+x^2)$.

Comment: The radius of the tubular neigborhood may not have a uniform positive lower bound. So the convolution might not lie in this neigborhood anymore.

Comment: @JohnMa You mean that it is possible for the tubular neighbourhood to become arbitrarily small due to non-compactness? (With respect to Mike Miller's example?)

Comment: Think of $N$ which has some open sets $U_i$ isometric to the large portion of the sphere of radius $1/i$. The neigborhood cannot be defined for a uniform positive radius.

Comment: @JohnMa I'm afraid, your example doesn't click with me. While Mike's example is understandable, it's one where there is just some tubular neighbourhood without uniform positive radius, while what I'm looking for, and you what were trying to explain, is some example where there is no tubular neighbourhood with such radius.

Comment: Well, consider the sphere of radius $r$. The tubular neigborhood $U$ can have length at most $r$: You cannot define continuously the projection $:\pi U\to S_r$ at the origin. Mike's example is not really a true example: one can just choose another better neigborhood. The failure is really due to the curvature of $N$ not bounded uniformly.

Comment: @JohnMa So, if I'm not mistaken, for fixed $r$ I could now choose the tubular neighbourhood (of the sphere) to just be smaller than $r$. In combination with your second-last comment: Do you mean, that my manifold might be isometric to (a sequence of?) spheres whose radii get arbitrarily small and thus cannot possess a tubular neighbourhood with uniform positive radius? (How does non-compactness cause this?)

Comment: @JohnMa The point of my comment was to see the picture, rather than to provide an example.

Comment: I mean, your noncompact $N$ has a family of pairwise disjoint open sets $U_i$, where each $U_i$ is isometric to a large part of the sphere with radius $1/i$. Then the tubular neigborhood around $U_i$ has to have radius smaller than $1/i$. So for all $\epsilon$, The smooth convolution approximation does not lie completely in this neigborhood.